# How to stream FIX Market Data to Excel using RTD

Tags: c#, .net, excel, fix-protocol, rtd

Currently, I'm running a C# Win Form application to get market data stream via FIX (Financial Information Exchange),

And also, I already build an RTD Server to update value to Excel spreadsheet. Currently, it's just a simple one, generate a random number and update the value to Excel every 50 ms.

My question now, is how to combine FIX market data stream to excel smoothly via RTD Server. Do I need a SQL Server in between?

Comment: Hi Frank. I think your question is a bit broad, a bit unclear, a bit opinion based. Let me give you a quick pointer: research the [QuickFIX/N .NET FIX engine](http://quickfixn.org/): `QuickFIX/n implements the FIX protocol on .NET. QuickFIX/n is 100% free and open source with a liberal license.`.

Comment: I already know about FIX. My question how to stream FIX market data to Excel via RTD.

Comment: RTD requires COM interface. Does .NET allow you to expose a COM interface?

Comment: Yes, I have built it, a simple one tho, so now I'm looking how to integrate RTD function with FIX market data full-refresh. I think my requirement so clear.

Comment: If you have a COM interface around FIX market data input written with QuickFIX/N, you should be able to integrate it with RDS as that's the technology used to embed it in Excel. If you have problems with any part of this setup, you will have to ask individual questions as the whole is just too broad for a question on Stack Overflow.